# PHPunit on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tdd

phpunit module is available In D-7 ?

as of now, am using details Core Tester Framework(simple test), which has DrupalWebTestCase class,

I want to make the TDD program on D 7, using PHP Unit class, please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

There is no ready to use integration class for PHPUnit testing in Drupal 7.

For what I've seen, the general consensus for TDD in the community is to use PHPunit to write code that do not rely on Drupal's API in TDD. Completed by a  light *integration layer* in Drupal, without using TDD. The idea is to reduce the friction between the tested/written code and Drupal.

This generally mean abstracting anything Drupal in a set of different services or functions, injected in the business logic classes you develop.

As an easy example, instead of using the `cache_get()` and `cache_set()` function in your code, write your code to use a `DrupalCacheInterface` instance. In the same fashion, instead of using Drupal's database API in you code, you rather rely on abstraction of the needed opérations. Under tests, you can provide mock implementation of the needed interface (either directly from Drupal, or specific to your own code). Your Drupal integration code is responsible for the injection of actual implementation.

For instance, with the following code while `MODULE_entity_load` is not teastbale with PHP Unit (because of access to the database and usage of the cache) you can test the behaviour of `_MODULE_entity_load` in PHP Unit as it does not actually depends on a bootstraped Drupal application.

```
<?php

  /**
   * Implements hook_entity_load().
   */
  function MODULE_entity_load($entities, $type) {
    return _MODULE_entity_load(
      $entities,
      $type,
      function($entity) {
        return db_query(...);
      },
      _cache_get_object($bin)
    );
  }

  /**
   * "Pure" function to handle entities load.
   */
  function _MODULE_entity_load($entities, $type, $queryData, DrupalCacheInterfac $cacheObject) {
    if ($type != 'node') return;
    forEach($entities as $entity) {
      $cache = $cacheObject->get('MODULE:' . $entity->nid);
      if ($cache && (time() < $cache->expire)) {
        $entity->MODULE_data = $queryData($entity->field_xyz);
        $cacheObject->set('MODULE:' . $node->nid, $entity->MODULE_data);
      }
      else {
        $entity->MODULE_data = $cache->data;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, @Pierre Buyle Right now there is no dedicated supported module available for the phpunit,

I have created tests folder in the root directory and added couple of test code, its started working, i can able to consume drupal functions For login authentication, i used `user_authenticate('root', 'admin123');`

Looks phpunit kick off is good, going to start next level in tdd.

Action items for phpunit

1. Downloaded composer and installed
2. Created composer.json inside wamp/bin/php5.12.x/php/phpunit/composer.json
3. added below snippet into composer.json

   {
       "require-dev": {
           "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*",
            "phpunit/dbunit": "1.2.*"
       }
   }
4. executed following commmand in the cmd 
   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpunit> composer update
5. Lot of files created inside phpunit folder, 
   added 
   ' C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpunit\phpunit' 
   in the system environment, PATH.    that's it
6. created 'tests' folder inside the application root directory
7. created test.php file and pasted below snippet.
8. executed the below command in CMD
   C:\wamp\www\tester>**phpunit test tests/test.php**
9. output for the above phpunit command instruction

[image: PHPUnit Output]

Now i can run the phpunit in drupal inside

Code Sample

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
// Bootstrap Drupal.
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

class test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

  public function testLoginChk(){
    print_r(user_authenticate('root', 'admin123'));
    $this->assertEquals(1,user_authenticate('root', 'admin123'));
  }

}
```

Please share your thought i am on the same path for drupal phpunit testing method.